# How to print * cube

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to print cube with empty inside using `*`.
I code next code but in prints this:

```
****** 


** 


** 


******
```

And I need this:

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

The questions is why I got spaces, and why it is not cube?
My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            if(i==1||j==1||i==5||j==5){
                System.out.print("*");
            }else {
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `System.out#println` instead of `System.out#print` for your spaces, which will create a new line each time you need to print a space.

Change it to `System.out#print` and use one `System.out#println` at the end of each line and you'll be fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            if(i==1||j==1||i==5||j==5){
                System.out.print("*");
            }else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```